# Limits amount of terms displayed? Is it possible?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom taxonomy/terms named "Cast". And it may contain lots of names sometimes even over 50 and it consume too much space of the theme.

[image]

Is it possible to limit the maximum terms displayed in post?

For example the limit is 15 names from that taxonomy so it only shows 15 and hides all others.

Comment: while I have upvoted it, I am not sure that limiting the number is the correct way to go bout it, as just using the random order the API returns might leave your main cast members out of the list. You probably need to think of better organization of your data to support smart information display

Comment: I would suggest hiding all but first 15 and display the rest with "Show all" in javascript. You might also consider adding a new custom taxonomy for the leading roles.

Answer (score 2):

As per the wordpress documentention, you can limit the showing terms by number.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

```
$limit_terms = get_terms( 'Cast', array(
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'number' => 50

    ) );
```